# Why can't I return a result from inside a JavaScript closure?

Tags: javascript, return, closures, underscore.js, memoization

I want the function foo() to close over the function it takes as an argument. Then when that function is called from inside the closure using bar(), I want to store the result in a cache before returning it. Then the next time bar() is called I want to check the cache for the answer and just return that (if possible) instead of evaluating the whole function. (Similar to memoize.)

I've written something that I think should work, but for some reason the first time bar() is called it won't return the result. It can log it to the console, but not return it. Why doesn't the first call to bar() return "baz"?

Thanks in advance for the help. I am new to programming, and still trying to understand closures. I have read a variety of articles explaining them but haven't seen anything that seemed like it explained this quirk.

```
foo = function(func) {
  var cache = [];
  var called = false;
  return function(){

    if(!called){
      called = true;
      var answer = func.apply(this, arguments);
      cache.push({arguments : answer});
      console.log("answer = " + answer);
      return answer;

    } else {
        console.log("retrieving answer from history");
        return cache[0].arguments;
    }

  };
};

var bar = foo(function(){ return "baz";});

bar();  //logs "answer = baz" to the console, returns nothing
bar();  //logs "retrieving answer from history", returns "baz"
```

Comment: The first call to bar logs "answer = baz" as well as returning "baz" for me.

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/fnr8w4y2/

Comment: Try `console.log(bar())` to see what it returns if you're executing the whole block at once.

Comment: Wow, you're right, it does. That's embarrassing. I have been writing and testing it on repl.it, where it has a problem. But it must be somthing involving their site. I should have tested it on JSfiddle (or just in the browser) before posting this question.

Thanks @Keylan and Andreas for pointing out what I should have already known.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the tip. Looks like that gives me "baz" like I was hoping. That's a debugging tip I'll be sure to use in the future.

Comment: @gmeyr: Yeah, if you put something in the console (or on repl.it maybe as wel), it'll only print the return value of the *last* statement.

Comment: @Bergi Gotcha. That's so helpful to know, thanks.